# Javascript indexOf giving wrong result during rerender, but correct during first render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, material-ui

I have the following code that I am rendering in my component.

```
<List> 
  {columns.map(column => {
      console.log(checked);
      console.log(checked.indexOf(column));
      console.log(column);
      return (
        <ListItem>
          <ListItemIcon>
            <Checkbox
              checked={checked.indexOf(column) !== -1}
            />
          </ListItemIcon>
          <ListItemText />
        </ListItem>
      );
    })}     
</List>
```

I will have the Checkbox checked if the value of checked.indexOf(column) is not -1. My initial state of "checked" is such that all my Checkboxes should be checked.

You can see that I have put three console.log's to see what is going on.

```
console.log(checked);
console.log(checked.indexOf(column));
console.log(column);
```

This component renders twice for some reason and during first render, this is the console output -

```
(24) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]0: {key: "Source_campname", title: "TS Camp Name", totalRow: true, totalRowCellName: "Total", customElement: ƒ}1: {key: "Tracker_campname", title: "TR Camp Name"}2: {key: "Source_impressions", title: "Impressions", defaultSort: "desc", totalRow: true}3: {key: "Source_clicks", title: "Banner Clicks", totalRow: true}4: {key: "Custom_banner_ctr", title: "Banner CTR", totalRow: true, customElement: ƒ, customSort: ƒ}5: {key: "custom_ecpm", title: "eCPM", totalRow: true, customElement: ƒ, customSort: ƒ}6: {key: "custom_ecpc", title: "eCPC", totalRow: true, customElement: ƒ, customSort: ƒ}7: {key: "Tracker_landerClicks", title: "Lander Clicks", totalRow: true}8: {key: "Tracker_offerClicks", title: "Offer Clicks", totalRow: true}9: {key: "Tracker_conversions", title: "Conversions", totalRow: true}10: {key: "Tracker_revenue", title: "Revenue", totalRow: true, customElement: ƒ, customSort: ƒ}11: {key: "Source_cost", title: "Cost", totalRow: true, customElement: ƒ, customSort: ƒ}12: {key: "custom_profit", title: "Profit", totalRow: true, customElement: ƒ, customSort: ƒ}13: {key: "custom_lander_ctr", title: "Lander CTR", totalRow: true, customElement: ƒ, customSort: ƒ}14: {key: "custom_cr", title: "CR", totalRow: true, customElement: ƒ, customSort: ƒ}15: {key: "custom_cv", title: "CV", totalRow: true, customElement: ƒ, customSort: ƒ}16: {key: "custom_roi", title: "ROI", totalRow: true, customElement: ƒ, customSort: ƒ}17: {key: "custom_epv", title: "EPV", totalRow: true, customElement: ƒ, customSort: ƒ}18: {key: "custom_epc", title: "EPC", totalRow: true, customElement: ƒ, customSort: ƒ}19: {key: "custom_ap", title: "AP", totalRow: true, customElement: ƒ, customSort: ƒ}20: {key: "database_id", title: "Database ID"}21: {key: "Tracker_country", title: "Country"}22: {key: "Source_name", title: "Traffic Source"}23: {key: "Tracker_name", title: "Tracker"}length: 24__proto__: Array(0)

22

{key: "Source_name", title: "Traffic Source"}
```

The value 22 is correct. But then component rerenders. Check out the console output then -

```
(24) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]0: {key: "Source_campname", title: "TS Camp Name", totalRow: true, totalRowCellName: "Total", customElement: ƒ}1: {key: "Tracker_campname", title: "TR Camp Name"}2: {key: "Source_impressions", title: "Impressions", defaultSort: "desc", totalRow: true}3: {key: "Source_clicks", title: "Banner Clicks", totalRow: true}4: {key: "Custom_banner_ctr", title: "Banner CTR", totalRow: true, customElement: ƒ, customSort: ƒ}5: {key: "custom_ecpm", title: "eCPM", totalRow: true, customElement: ƒ, customSort: ƒ}6: {key: "custom_ecpc", title: "eCPC", totalRow: true, customElement: ƒ, customSort: ƒ}7: {key: "Tracker_landerClicks", title: "Lander Clicks", totalRow: true}8: {key: "Tracker_offerClicks", title: "Offer Clicks", totalRow: true}9: {key: "Tracker_conversions", title: "Conversions", totalRow: true}10: {key: "Tracker_revenue", title: "Revenue", totalRow: true, customElement: ƒ, customSort: ƒ}11: {key: "Source_cost", title: "Cost", totalRow: true, customElement: ƒ, customSort: ƒ}12: {key: "custom_profit", title: "Profit", totalRow: true, customElement: ƒ, customSort: ƒ}13: {key: "custom_lander_ctr", title: "Lander CTR", totalRow: true, customElement: ƒ, customSort: ƒ}14: {key: "custom_cr", title: "CR", totalRow: true, customElement: ƒ, customSort: ƒ}15: {key: "custom_cv", title: "CV", totalRow: true, customElement: ƒ, customSort: ƒ}16: {key: "custom_roi", title: "ROI", totalRow: true, customElement: ƒ, customSort: ƒ}17: {key: "custom_epv", title: "EPV", totalRow: true, customElement: ƒ, customSort: ƒ}18: {key: "custom_epc", title: "EPC", totalRow: true, customElement: ƒ, customSort: ƒ}19: {key: "custom_ap", title: "AP", totalRow: true, customElement: ƒ, customSort: ƒ}20: {key: "database_id", title: "Database ID"}21: {key: "Tracker_country", title: "Country"}22: {key: "Source_name", title: "Traffic Source"}23: {key: "Tracker_name", title: "Tracker"}length: 24__proto__: Array(0)

-1

{key: "Source_name", title: "Traffic Source"}
```

This time the value -1 is wrong because {key: "Tracker_campname", title: "TR Camp Name"} is present inside the array as you can see above.

As the second render is wrong, my checkboxes are not correctly checked. 
I am stuck with this for 6 hours now. Any idea what is going on here?

If you are interested in the full code of this component you can read it below. This will show what is "checked" array -

```
function getModalStyle() {
    const top = 50;
    const left = 50;

    return {
      top: `${top}%`,
      left: `${left}%`,
      transform: `translate(-${top}%, -${left}%)`,
      overflow: 'scroll',
      maxHeight: '80%'
    };
}

function ThanosTableToolbar({ title, columns, visibleColumns, onColumnChange }) {
    const [viewListOpen, setViewListOpen] = useState(false); 
    const [modalStyle] = useState(getModalStyle);
    const [checked, setChecked] = useState(visibleColumns);

    const handleViewList = () => {
        setViewListOpen(true);
    };

    const handleViewListClose = () => {
        setViewListOpen(false);
    };

    const handleToggle = value => () => {
        let allChecked = [...columns];
        let newChecked = [...checked];
        let currentIndex = checked.indexOf(value);
        let difference;
        let diffIndex;
        if (currentIndex === -1) {
            newChecked.push(value);
            difference = allChecked.filter(x => !newChecked.includes(x));
            for(let i=0; i<difference.length; i++) {
                diffIndex = allChecked.indexOf(difference[i]);
                allChecked.splice(diffIndex, 1);
            }   
            setChecked(allChecked);
        } else {
          newChecked.splice(currentIndex, 1);
          setChecked(newChecked);
        }
    };

    useEffect(() => { // Need to use useEffect as setState is async
        onColumnChange(checked);
    }, [checked]);

    return (
        <Toolbar
            className={clsx(classes.root)}
        > 
            <Typography className={classes.title} variant="h6" id="tableTitle" component="div">
                { title }
            </Typography>
            <Tooltip title="Add Or Remove Columns">
                <IconButton aria-label="add or remove columns" onClick={handleViewList}>
                    <ViewColumnIcon />
                </IconButton>
            </Tooltip>
            <Modal
                open={viewListOpen} 
                onClose={handleViewListClose} 
            >
                <div style={modalStyle} className={classes.modal}>
                    <Typography style={{fontWeight: 'bold'}} align="center">Add Or Remove Columns</Typography> 
                    <List className={classes.root}> 
                        {columns.map(column => {
                            const labelId = `checkbox-list-label-${column.key}`;
                            console.log(checked);
                            console.log(checked.indexOf(column));
                            console.log(column);
                            return (
                              <ListItem key={column.key} role={undefined} dense button onClick={handleToggle(column)}>
                                <ListItemIcon>
                                  <Checkbox
                                    edge="start"
                                    checked={checked.indexOf(column) !== -1}
                                    tabIndex={-1}
                                    disableRipple
                                    inputProps={{ 'aria-labelledby': labelId }}
                                  />
                                </ListItemIcon>
                                <ListItemText id={labelId} primary={column.title} />
                              </ListItem>
                            );
                          })}     
                    </List> 
                </div>
            </Modal>
        </Toolbar>
    );
}

export default ThanosTableToolbar;
```

Columns is an array that looks like this.

```
const columns = [
        {
            key: 'Source_campname',
            title: 'TS Camp Name',
            customElement: function(row) {
                return(
                  <CampaignsClick 
                        database_id = {row.database_id} 
                        Source_campname = {row.Source_campname}
                    />
                );
            },
            totalRow: true,
            totalRowCellName: 'Total'
        },
        {
            key: 'Tracker_campname',
            title: 'TR Camp Name'
        },
        {
            key: 'Source_impressions',
            title: 'Impressions',
            defaultSort: 'desc',
            totalRow: true
        },
        {
            key: 'Source_clicks',
            title: 'Banner Clicks',
            totalRow: true
        },
        {
            key: 'Custom_banner_ctr',
            title: 'Banner CTR',
            customElement: function(row) {
                let numb = row.Source_clicks / row.Source_impressions * 100;
                return numb.toFixed(2);
            },
            customSort: function(row) {
                let numb = row.Source_clicks / row.Source_impressions * 100;
                if(isFinite(numb)) return numb;
                else return 0; 
            },
            totalRow: true
        },
        {
            key: 'custom_ecpm',
            title: 'eCPM',
            customElement: function(row) {
                let numb = row.Source_cost / row.Source_impressions * 1000;
                return numb.toFixed(3); 
            },
            customSort: function(row) {
                let numb = row.Source_cost / row.Source_impressions * 1000;
                if(isFinite(numb)) return numb;
                else return 0; 
            },
            totalRow: true             
        },
        {
            key: 'custom_ecpc',
            title: 'eCPC',
            customElement: function(row) {
                let numb = row.Source_cost / row.Source_clicks;
                return numb.toFixed(3); 
            },
            customSort: function(row) {
                let numb = row.Source_cost / row.Source_clicks;
                if(isFinite(numb)) return numb;
                else return 0; 
            },
            totalRow: true  
        },
        {
            key: 'Tracker_landerClicks',
            title: 'Lander Clicks',
            totalRow: true                
        },
        {
            key: 'Tracker_offerClicks',
            title: 'Offer Clicks',
            totalRow: true
        },
        {
            key: 'Tracker_conversions',
            title: 'Conversions',
            totalRow: true
        },
        {
            key: 'Tracker_revenue', 
            title: 'Revenue',
            customElement: function(row) {
                let numb = row.Tracker_revenue;
                return numb.toFixed(2); 
            },
            customSort: function(row) {
                return row.Tracker_revenue;
            },
            totalRow: true
        },
        {
            key: 'Source_cost', 
            title: 'Cost',
            customElement: function(row) {
                let numb = row.Source_cost;
                return numb.toFixed(2); 
            },
            customSort: function(row) {
                return row.Source_cost;
            },
            totalRow: true 
        },
        {
            key: 'custom_profit',
            title: 'Profit',
            customElement: function(row) {
                let numb = row.Tracker_revenue - row.Source_cost;
                return numb.toFixed(2); 
            },
            customSort: function(row) {
                let numb = row.Tracker_revenue - row.Source_cost;
                if(isFinite(numb)) return numb;
                else return 0; 
            },
            totalRow: true
        },
        {
            key: 'custom_lander_ctr',
            title: 'Lander CTR',
            customElement: function(row) {
                let numb = row.Tracker_offerClicks / row.Tracker_landerClicks * 100;
                return numb.toFixed(2); 
            },
            customSort: function(row) {
                let numb = row.Tracker_offerClicks / row.Tracker_landerClicks * 100;
                if(isFinite(numb)) return numb;
                else return 0; 
            },
            totalRow: true
        },
        {
            key: 'custom_cr',
            title: 'CR',
            customElement: function(row) {
                let numb = row.Tracker_conversions / row.Tracker_offerClicks * 100;
                return numb.toFixed(2); 
            },
            customSort: function(row) {
                let numb = row.Tracker_conversions / row.Tracker_offerClicks * 100;
                if(isFinite(numb)) return numb;
                else return 0; 
            },
            totalRow: true
        },
        {
            key: 'custom_cv',
            title: 'CV',
            customElement: function(row) {
                let numb = row.Tracker_conversions / row.Tracker_landerClicks * 100;
                return numb.toFixed(2); 
            },
            customSort: function(row) {
                let numb = row.Tracker_conversions / row.Tracker_landerClicks * 100;
                if(isFinite(numb)) return numb;
                else return 0; 
            },
            totalRow: true
        },
        {
            key: 'custom_roi',
            title: 'ROI',
            customElement: function(row) {
                let numb = (row.Tracker_revenue - row.Source_cost) / row.Source_cost * 100;
                return numb.toFixed(2); 
            },
            customSort: function(row) {
                let numb = (row.Tracker_revenue - row.Source_cost) / row.Source_cost * 100;
                if(isFinite(numb)) return numb;
                else return 0; 
            },
            totalRow: true
        },
        {
            key: 'custom_epv',
            title: 'EPV',
            customElement: function(row) {
                let numb = row.Tracker_revenue / row.Tracker_landerClicks;
                return numb.toFixed(3); 
            },
            customSort: function(row) {
                let numb = row.Tracker_revenue / row.Tracker_landerClicks;
                if(isFinite(numb)) return numb;
                else return 0; 
            },
            totalRow: true
        },
        {
            key: 'custom_epc',
            title: 'EPC',
            customElement: function(row) {
                let numb = row.Tracker_revenue / row.Tracker_offerClicks;
                return numb.toFixed(3); 
            },
            customSort: function(row) {
                let numb = row.Tracker_revenue / row.Tracker_offerClicks;
                if(isFinite(numb)) return numb;
                else return 0; 
            },
            totalRow: true
        },
        {
            key: 'custom_ap',
            title: 'AP',
            customElement: function(row) {
                let numb = row.Tracker_revenue / row.Tracker_conversions;
                return numb.toFixed(2); 
            },
            customSort: function(row) {
                let numb = row.Tracker_revenue / row.Tracker_conversions;
                if(isFinite(numb)) return numb;
                else return 0; 
            },
            totalRow: true
        },
        {
            key: 'database_id',
            title: 'Database ID'
        },
        {
            key: 'Tracker_country',
            title: 'Country'
        },
        {
            key: 'Source_name',
            title: 'Traffic Source'
        },
        {
            key: 'Tracker_name',
            title: 'Tracker'
        }
    ];
```

If you want to know a bit more (Like what visibleColumns are) you can check the main code from the library that I am building here - https://github.com/codenamethanos/materialui-table/blob/master/src/lib/components/ThanosTable.js

Comment: The array data that you've mentioned is not showing up, can you edit the snippet and add the complete one?

Comment: You need to show the code that sets `checked` and `columns`. `checked.indexOf(column)` is checking if the exact object `column` is in `checked`. A different object that has the same key and title won't do the trick.

Comment: @RyanCogswell I added more information now. I thought it will be too long, but since you mentioned I added it.

Comment: @ZainZafar I have added more details to the question now. Will that do?

Comment: Whenever that happens, you gotta look really hard for that Number to String conversion you didn't notice.

Comment: Please create a [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) with the simplest possible code that reproduces your problem.